# How to use a single named parameter after *args

Tags: python, keyword-argument

How can I use single `**kwargs` in my program? I need it to set a port number in an application uses sockets. I have to use `**kwargs` because I use `*args` as well so I can't just add `port=xxxx` in my function arguments.

```
def myFunction(*args, **kwargs):
   ... 
   socket.connect(("xx.xx.xx.xx", kwargs.values()))
   ... 

myFunction("something", "other", port = xxxx)
```

I'm now using `kwargs.values()` to set the port number, but it isn't good idea I think.

Comment: Why do you want kwargs, not just a named argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want `kwargs`, I thought that I can't just add `port=xxxx` in declaration parameters in my function while I have `*args`

### Python 3

In Python 3 it's possible to define a paramter after `*args`:

```
>>> def func(*args, port):
...     print(port)
...     print(args)
... 
>>> func('something', 'args', port='8000')
8000
('something', 'args')
```

However this will generate a syntax error in Python 2.

To adapt this to your code you can use:

```
#python3 only
def func(*args, port):
    socket.connect(('xx.xx.xx.xx', port))
```

### A more natural solution: using the **kwargs itself (Python 2 and 3)

```
>>> def func(*args, **kwargs):
...     print(args)
...     print(kwargs)
... 
>>> func('something', 'other', port='8000')
('something', 'other')
{'port': '8000'}
```

As you can see, you can pull the `port` parameter if it is provided, in the `kwargs` dict

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
   socket.connect(('xx.xx.xx.xx', kwargs['port']))
```

If you want to have a default value like [@wovano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316764/how-to-use-a-single-named-parameter-after-args/35317152?noredirect=1#comment137673921_35317152) suggested :

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
   socket.connect(('xx.xx.xx.xx', kwargs.get('port', default_port)))
```

Call it using:

```
func('something', 'other', port='8000')
```

Or using the default port value:

```
func('something', 'other')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `**`, you get a dictionary. So you can access the values by using the name of the argument as key.

```
def myFunction(*args, **kwargs):
   ... 
   socket.connect(("xx.xx.xx.xx", kwargs["port"]))
   ... 

myFunction("something", "other", port = xxxx)
```

Answer (score -1):

> I have to use **kwargs because I use *args also so I can't just add "port = xxxx" in my function arguments.

You sure can.

```
def myFunction(*args, port=None):
   ... 
   socket.connect(("xx.xx.xx.xx", port))
   ... 

myFunction("something", "other", port = xxxx)
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, python2 requires the splat arguments defined after the explicit arguments.  Therefore, you would not be able to preserve the order of arguments desired.  The alternative is to define the function as such and assume that the consumer will pass in a parameter named `port`.  I would always choose explicitly named functions over this approach, given the choice.

```
def myFunction(*args, **kwargs):
   ... 
   socket.connect(("xx.xx.xx.xx", port))
   ... 

myFunction("something", "other", port = xxxx)
```

Comment: This throws SyntaxError

Comment: This is only possible in Python 3.

Comment: The second example will not work. `port` is not defined in the scope of `myFunction`. You have to use `kwargs["port"]`

Answer (score -3):

Just pass it as you got them :D

```
def myFunction(*args, **kwargs):
   ... 
   socket.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", **kwargs)
   ... 

myFunction("something", "other", port = xxxx)
```